# Unrecognized Encoding

Tags: warnings

I struggle to figure out why this warning comes when I open my tex file:
[image]

I point out that I manage to open the file and work on it and also to produce the pdf version, but a coauthor of mine cannot and I suspect it is because of this warning. In addition, I tried to search for presumably unsupported characters in the text such as à,é,è,ì,ò,ù,*,# and delete them  but still does not work. 
Can anyone help? Any clue? 
thank you in advance

Comment: Typo in the file, I guess. It probably contains a line such as `% !TeX encoding = UTC-8`. Press OK and fix the faulty letter.

Answer (score 1):

Since the UTC-8 encoding doesn't exist, the issue is quite likely due to the file having the line

```
% !TeX encoding = UTC-8
```

at the top. Indeed, if I write the file

```latex
% !TeX encoding = UTC-8

é ß ö
```

just to check the accented letters after the fact, and try to open it with TeXworks, I get the info window

[image]
If I press OK, I see

[image]

so nothing bad has happened. Change `UTC-8` into `UTF-8`, save and go along.